# Python re.search with variable in page source

Tags: python

I was wondering how can I search the data that is loaded from a page with a .`read()` and search for a variable within that search in a while statement. Here is what I wrote:

```
match2 = re.search(r"=profile\.php\?id=" + str(link) + ">(.+?)</a>, <a href=profile\.php\?id=(.+?)>", home)
```

The page basically just lists all the user profiles and I'm trying to make it read each one and view their profile; pretty simple except for the fact that I can't get the user ids set as a variable from `link = match2.group(2)` to work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but I strongly suggest you look at [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). It's an HTML parser that lets you search for values in a much more structured manner. In this case, you could loop across all the items in the list of user profiles, and extract the information you want out of each one in turn.